# CUDA: Max of array, how to prevent write collisions?

Tags: cuda

I have an array of doubles stored in GPU global memory and i need to find the maximum value in it. I have read some texts about parallel reduction, so i know that one should divide the array between blocks and make them find their "global maximum", and so on.
But they never seem to address the issue of threads trying to write to the same memory position simultaneously.

Let's say that local_max=0.0 in the beginning of a block execution. Then each thread reads their value from the input vector, decides that is larger than local_max, and then try to write their value to local_max. When all of this happens at the exact same time (atleast when inside the same warp), how can this work and end up with the actual maximum within this block?

I would think either an atomic function or some kind of lock or critical section would be needed, but i haven't seen this addressed in the answers i have found. (ex http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your questions are contained in the very document you linked to, and the SDK reduction example shows concrete implementations of the reduction concept.

For completeness, here is a concrete example of a reduction kernel:

```
template <typename T, int BLOCKSIZE>
__global__ reduction(T *inputvals, T *outputvals, int N)
{
    __shared__ volatile T data[BLOCKSIZE];

    T maxval = inputvals[threadIdx.x];
    for(int i=blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i<N; i+=blockDim.x) 
    {
        maxfunc(maxval, inputvals[i]);
    }

    data[threadIdx.x] = maxval;
    __syncthreads();

    // Here maxfunc(a,b) sets a to the minimum of a and b
    if (threadIdx.x < 32) {

        for(int i=32+threadIdx.x; i < BLOCKSIZE; i+= 32) {
            maxfunc(data[threadIdx.x], data[i]);
        }

        if (threadIdx.x < 16) maxfunc(data[threadIdx.x], data[threadIdx.x+16]);
        if (threadIdx.x < 8) maxfunc(data[threadIdx.x], data[threadIdx.x+8]);
        if (threadIdx.x < 4) maxfunc(data[threadIdx.x], data[threadIdx.x+4]);
        if (threadIdx.x < 2) maxfunc(data[threadIdx.x], data[threadIdx.x+2]);
        if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
            maxfunc(data[0], data[1]);
            outputvals[blockIdx.x] = data[0];
        }
    }
}
```

The key point is using the synchronization that is implicit within a warp to perform the reduction in shared memory. The result is a single per-block maximum value. A second reduction pass is required to reduce the set of block maximums to the global maximum (often it is faster to o this on the host). In this example, `maxvals` is the "compare and set" function which could be as simple as

```
template<T>
__device__ void maxfunc(T & a, T  & b)
{
    a = (b > a) ? b : a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the volatile-qualifier for the shared array really needed?

Comment: On Fermi, it most definitely is. Assembler optimization can wind up holding values in register rather than writing them back to shared memory which breaks implicit shared memory synchronization between threads in the same warp.

Comment: I get "error: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "double &" to initializer of type "volatile double"" at the calls to maxfunc by the way. (Rewritten for double instead of templating, for simplicity.)

Comment: So rewrite maxfunc to take volatile argumenta. It is now your code, not mine.........

Answer (score 2):

Dont' cook your own code, use some [thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) (included in version 4.0 of the Cuda sdk) :

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{

    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(10000);
    thrust::sequence(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end());
    // show hvec
    thrust::copy(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), 
                 std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

    // transfer to device
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec = h_vec;

    int max_dvec_value = *thrust::max_element(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end()); 

    std::cout << "max value: " << max_dvec_value << "\n";
    return 0;    
}
```

And watch out that thrust::max_element returns a pointer.

Comment: So does thrust::max_element return a host pointer, i.e. it automatically copies the result to the host? Anyway, would it be possible to pass a reguler CUDA device array (created by cudaMalloc) to thrust::max_element ?

Comment: Found the answer to the last question here: http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide

Comment: While using thrust::max_element is probably a better bet for production code, but the concepts involved in the reduction implementation and why it performs well are generally applicable to CUDA development.  If you choose not to understand how to get good performance out of CUDA, then you might as well not use it at all.

Comment: I am in fact planning to implement it myself, i'm just exploring the options. After testing with vector lengths in the tens of thousands, the simple CPU implementation was actually faster than thrust. So i guess i'll try to squeeze more performance out of it by "cooking my own code".

Answer (score 1):

Your question is clearly answered in the document you link to.  I think you just need to spend some more time reading it and understanding the CUDA concepts used in it.  In particular, I would focus on shared memory, the __syncthreads() method, and how to uniquely identify a thread while inside a kernel.  Additionally, you should try to understand why the reduction may need to be run in 2 passes to find the global maximum.